# Is this an equivalent definition of a nilpotent group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

I'll try to make it quick. In an exercise, I'm encountering this definition of a nilpotent group:

> A group $G$ is *nilpotent* if there is a finite series of subgroups $\{e\} \subseteq G_n \subseteq G_{n - 1} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq G_0 = G$ with each $G_i \lhd G$ and $G_i/G_{i + 1}$ abelian.

But the definition seems different than any I've seen subsequently, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group). Is this an equivalent definition of a nilpotent group?

Comment: This definition is incorrect; it defines solvable groups. You can check that it’s satisfied by $S_3$ which is the smallest solvable non-nilpotent group.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the definition was off. By the way, the exercise is from the textbook on Galois theory by Garling. Also, the definition of solvable groups in the textbook requires a subnormal series with cyclic factor groups.

Comment: That's equivalent (for finite groups anyway); you can refine a subnormal series with abelian factors to a subnormal series with cyclic factors.

Comment: Could there be a typo in the definition of nilpotent in the exercise? Any idea on a quick fix?

Comment: You want $G_{i+1}/G_i\leq Z(G/G_i)$